# Is it a requirement to add NOT NULL when defining a column with IDENTITY(1, 1) key word?

Tags: t-sql

The way I understand it, **IDENTITY (1, 1)** means that we won't provide any data for that column. Sql Server will, adding each time 1 to the value of the previously created row.

why not this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  MyTableID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY  
)
```

but rather this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  MyTableID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY 
)
```

Why should I add **NOT NULL** on the definition of such a column? Is that implies that Sql Server could generate NULL values??

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's optional in this case.

Irrespective of the setting of [`ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` / `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx)  the column that will be added will not be `NULL`-able.

You would get an error if you were to try and explicitly set an `IDENTITY` column (or one participating in a primary key constraint) to allow `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

No; when specifying a column as either a PRIMARY KEY (in the definition) or as an IDENTITY, there is no need to specify NOT NULL.